# javascript .replace width tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Looking for help with a javascript reg ex replacement. What I need, is to replace all instances of

```
width="100">
```

With

```
style="width: 100px;"
```

But the actual px value is variable which is what is causing issues for me. I know reg expression is the way to go but I dont quite understand it.

This is a similar question but doesn't solve the issue for me:
[JavaScript Regex Replace Width Attribute Matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812258/javascript-regex-replace-width-attribute-matching)

The reason this is a problem is because of the HTML generated by TinyMce...

Comment: It's going to be more complicated than that. What if the element already has a `style` attribute on it? It's not allowed to have two of them (e.g., after the change).

Comment: It's better to target specific elements, for example *this* div, or *that* table.

Comment: I've verified that there will not be another `style` attribute and the function will only be run on a certain div container

Comment: would something like this help: http://regex101.com/r/oW2xP7/1?

Comment: What's the objection to using DOM-manipulation or jQuery? Something like `$('*[width]').width()`?

Comment: No objection, open to any suggestions.

Comment: Do you use any JavaScript libraries? (jQuery, for instance?)

Comment: Yes jQuery is loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

- Using a regular expression
- Parsing the HTML and working with the DOM (preferred)

#### Using a regular expression

The expression is fairly straightforward:

```
str = str.replace(/\bwidth="(\d+)"/g, 'style="width: $1px"');
```

The `$1` in the replacement string is filled in with the content of the first capture group.

Example:

```js
var str = '<div width="100">Stuff here</div><div width="240">More stuff here</div>';
display("Before: '" + str + "'");
str = str.replace(/\bwidth="(\d+)"/g, 'style="width: $1px"');
display("After: '" + str + "'");

function display(msg) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "<p>" +
    String(msg)
      .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;") +
    "</p>"
  );
}
```

But note that that will:

1. Replace `width="nnn"` *everywhere* in the string, even if not inside a start tag
2. End up adding a second `style` attribute to a tag that already has one

If that's okay, great; if not, you might want to parse the HTML, process the resulting parsed DOM nodes, and then serialize it again.

#### Parsing the HTML and working with the DOM

A better option is to parse the HTML and work with the DOM. You've said that the HTML will be for a `div`, so we don't have to worry about things like standalone table cells, etc.

Here's a simple parsing and updating example:

```js
var str = '<div width="100">Stuff here</div><div width="240">More stuff here</div>';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
update(div.childNodes);
display("Before: '" + str + "'");
str = div.innerHTML;
display("After: '" + str + "'");

function update(nodes) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes, function(node) {
    var width;
    if (node.nodeType === 1) { // An element
      width = node.getAttribute("width");
      if (width) {
        node.removeAttribute("width");
        node.style.width = width + "px";
      }
      update(node.childNodes);
    }
  });
}

function display(msg) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "<p>" +
    String(msg)
    .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    .replace(/</g, "&lt;") +
    "</p>"
  );
}
```

Comment: Been trying to implement this solution but for some reason it wont work: `<script>function replaceFunc() { var str = document.getElementById("resultsPnl"); str = str.innerHTML; str = str.replace(/\bwidth="(\d+)"/g, 'style="width: $1px"'); document.getElementById("resultsPnl").innerHTML = str; } if ($('#resultsPnl').length) { window.onload = replaceFunc; } </script>`

Comment: @KieranQuinn: Is `resultsPn1` the element with the `width` attribute? Remember that `innerHTML` is what's **inside** the element, it doesn't include the element's start or end tags.

Comment: Suggestion: use `.children` instead of `.childNodes` - this removes the need for `if( node.nodeType === 1)` because only element nodes will be returned.

Comment: Yes its the contents of that div I need to replace rather than the div itself

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I thought about it, but I keep forgetting how well supported `children` is, and the check is trivial in this case.

Comment: @KieranQuinn: That should work, then, provided it has the content in it when you run that code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Supported. Older versions of IE (6-8) erroneously include comment nodes, though, but since I find HTML comments to be never used (I prefer PHP comments so bandwidth isn't wasted) I don't consider this an issue.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Thanks, v. useful. I think that must be why I still don't use it (IE8 is lingering). People are using HTML comments more these days, thanks to things like KnockoutJS (e.g., they actually get used for something client-side).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, fair enough. In that case, I guess use of `.children[]` will remain reliant on a certain assumption (namely, "there will be no HTML comments in the way") that may or may not be reliable. I learned too! :D

Comment: Tried the parsing example, didnt work:( We're still running IE8. Also, when I tried the code above I added it to the bottom of the file

Comment: Finally got there. So the problem I had was with the quotation marks around `str.replace(/\bwidth="(\d+)"/g,`. When I removed them and went with `str.replace(/\bwidth=(\d+)/g,` it seems to work great. Ty sir

Answer (score 0):

My first thought also was to work with the DOM instead of using RegEx. Instead of iterating over all the elements, we could just use `querySelector`, which supports attribute selectors.

```
var html = '<img src="//placehold.it/100x100" alt="" style="100px;">'+
           '<img src="//placehold.it/120x120" alt="" width="120" style="border: 2px solid steelblue;">'+
           '<img src="//placehold.it/140x140" alt="" width="140">',
    wrap = document.createElement('div'),
    nodes;

wrap.innerHTML = html;

nodes = wrap.querySelectorAll('[width]');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes, function(el) {
    var width = el.getAttribute('width');
    if(width) {
        el.removeAttribute('width');
        el.style.width = width+'px';
    }
});
```